# update Qt creator under windows

Tags: qt

I have Qt creator 2.4.1 based on Qt 4.7.4 and I want to update everything using "maintain Qt SDK" tool. When I try to update components, tool says that there are no updates. Shall I just reinstall everything or I can add some repositories and everything will be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK isn't updated anymore. If you want the latest versions, you need to download and install them.

Comment: It looks like for minor updates you can use the MaintenanceTool (see doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html). But for major ones, one needs to download and install them, indeed.